# How to perfom Massiveinsert in OrientDB .Net API?

Tags: c#, .net, orientdb

I am using [OrientDB-NET Library](https://github.com/orientechnologies/OrientDB-NET.binary) but did not found any efficient solution for bulk insert. I have 1M Edges between almost 6K vertex currently i am using the following code and it take around ~30mins (indeed worst performance as compared to SQL Server Data Load ) on my machine Core i7 6th Gen, 2.5GHz, 8GB RAM.
Found the solution of MassiveInsert in Java API. But didn't find any solution in .NET.

```
object locker = new object(); 
Parallel.ForEach(_listRating, r=>
{
    lock (locker)
    {
      oDB.Command(" create edge rated from (select from Users where userID = " + r.userID + ") to (select from Movies where MovieID = " + r.movieID + "  ) set rating =" + r.Ratings + "  ");

    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know oriental but parallel foreach with lock is useless

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send many `create edge` as one query use [SQL Batch](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-batch.html)

```
begin;
  CREATE EDGE E FROM #34:3349  TO #32:3349;
  CREATE EDGE E FROM #41:10971 TO #33:3348;
  ...
commit retry 100;
```

In my case (PHP), the acceleration was quite high.